# ListBox Not showing data

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox

this is my XAML of listbox

```
<ListBox Height="100" Margin="12,12,8,0" Name="CategoriesList" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Id}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="40" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

this is my class

```
public class Categories 
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }

    public Categories() { }

    public Categories(string value, string text) 
    {
        this.Id = value;
        this.Title = text;
    }
}
```

here is the assignment code with dummy data

```
        List<Categories> categoriesList = new List<Categories>();
        categoriesList.Add(new Categories("1", "One"));
        categoriesList.Add(new Categories("2", "Two"));
        categoriesList.Add(new Categories("3", "Three"));
        categoriesList.Add(new Categories("4", "Four"));
        categoriesList.Add(new Categories("5", "Five"));
        CategoriesList.ItemsSource = categoriesList;
```

the list is blank but items are 5, that means title is not displayed...can u please help me out

Comment: And y the hell is combo-box not there in WP7?? :(

Comment: There is a ListPicker in Silverlight Toolkit (third-party combobox)

Comment: Make your fields public. This is a requirement for binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as said by @Ku6opr making variables public made the list running...thanks to him

```
public class Categories 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Categories() { }

    public Categories(string value, string text) 
    {
        this.Id = value;
        this.Title = text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to set/bind the `ItemSource` attribute of the `ListBox` to a public list of categories, as follows ItemSource = {Binding categoriesList}

Judging by this (wherever it may reside):

> 

```
List<Categories> categoriesList = new List<Categories>();
        categoriesList.Add(new Categories("1", "One"));
        categoriesList.Add(new Categories("2", "Two"));
        categoriesList.Add(new Categories("3", "Three"));
        categoriesList.Add(new Categories("4", "Four"));
        categoriesList.Add(new Categories("5", "Five"));
        CategoriesList.ItemsSource = categoriesList;
```

You're using a locally declared List variable.

Also if you intend to alter the list contents in any way then you'll find things easier if your `Categories` list is an `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: -1: He *does* set the `ItemsSource` to his list...: `CategoriesList.ItemsSource = categoriesList;`

Comment: I meant to say that a binding to a public List<Categories>

Comment: That is not a problem at all. If you are assigning the variable directly to `ItemsSource` it doesn't matter whether it is a local variable or not.